# QBXML InvoiceAdd Error 3250 Feature Not Enabled Or Available

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I have been able to create basic invoices via the API with single line items. These have not shipping etc.

Now, when trying to add complete Invoice with the Shipping Line Item (`Type = Other Charge`). I am getting error `3250 - This feature is not enabled or not available in this version of QuickBooks.`

`QB Version:` Enterprise 2018 Manufacturing Edition w/ Advanced Inventory

## InvoiceAddRq Not Working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <InvoiceAddRq requestID="INV-CREATE|8000B526-1518041862">
            <InvoiceAdd>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>8000B526-1518041862</ListID>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TemplateRef>
                    <FullName>FS Invoice</FullName>
                </TemplateRef>
                <TxnDate>2018-02-07</TxnDate>
                <PONumber>WEB-44364</PONumber>
                <TermsRef>
                    <FullName>Prepaid</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
                <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                    <FullName>Sales Tax</FullName>
                </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <Memo>Web Order Id: 44364</Memo>
                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>Shipping Fees</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Shipping Charges</Desc>
                    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
                    <Rate>8.95</Rate>
                    <Amount>8.95</Amount>
                    <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        <FullName>Non</FullName>
                    </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                </InvoiceLineAdd>
                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <ListID>80000086-1512586876</ListID>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Product Description</Desc>
                    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
                    <Rate>22.99</Rate>
                    <Amount>22.99</Amount>
                    <InventorySiteLocationRef>
                        <FullName>RSM</FullName>
                    </InventorySiteLocationRef>
                    <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        <FullName>Tax</FullName>
                    </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                </InvoiceLineAdd>
            </InvoiceAdd>
        </InvoiceAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

## Simple InvoiceAddRq Working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <InvoiceAddRq requestID="INV-CREATE|8000B543-1518105265">
            <InvoiceAdd>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>8000B543-1518105265</ListID>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TemplateRef>
                    <FullName>FS Invoice</FullName>
                </TemplateRef>
                <TxnDate>2018-02-08</TxnDate>
                <PONumber>WEB-44380</PONumber>
                <TermsRef>
                    <FullName>Prepaid</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
                <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                    <FullName>Out of State</FullName>
                </ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <Memo>Web Order Id: 44380</Memo>
                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>WBQB-TMP</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>Temp Product Entry. Please enter data from WB.</Desc>
                    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
                    <Rate>1.00</Rate>
                    <Amount>1.00</Amount>
                    <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        <FullName>Non</FullName>
                    </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                </InvoiceLineAdd>
            </InvoiceAdd>
        </InvoiceAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

[image]

I have tried searching the docs for some setting in QB I may need to change but have come up empty. Hoping someone can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is usually related to something you don't have turned on in QuickBooks.

If you were to create this same invoice in QuickBooks directly, would you be able to choose all of those options?

Have you tried creating an invoice with an *absolute minimum* of information? e.g. without the sales tax, without the inventory sites, without the template, without the sales terms, etc.?

I'd bet that you either:

- Don't have sales tax enabled

or

- Don't have inventory site location tracking enabled

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong option for the inventory site. I was using `InventorySiteLocationRef` and I needed to be using `InventorySiteRef`